# There are hold-outs but 263 years later

Tags: word-meaning

I understand (or guess) that "hold-outs" here refers to "people who resist evidence and truth."  Am I on the right track?

> (Harvard Professor) Steven Pinker Retweeted
> Philip E. Tetlock tweeted:
> **There are hold-outs but 263 years later**, political psychology is edging toward Samuel Johnson’s views:
> “Credulity--confidence of opinion too great for the evidence from which opinion is derived--we find to be a general weakness imputed by
> every sect and party to all others”(1758)

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/PTetlock/status/1389307899411898391)

Comment: It's a ***facetious*** (jokey, tongue-in-cheek) usage intended to imply that anyone who *doesn't* agree with whatever Johnson said (which presumably Pinker and Tetlock *do* agree with) are at least 263 years ***behind the times***. It's entirely a matter of opinion whether Pinker et al's current ideas are based on "evidence and truth" (though obviously he and Tetlock would insist their ideas *are* "evidence-based", since just about everyone does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it necessarily means people who resist evidence and truth, but rather, some people in the field of political psychology who are not edging toward SJ's views.